# V-If not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I used a v-if/else statement in my html. These depend on a watcher. In my watcher I also used a `setTimeout()` function to clone an api call. When I try to set the isLoading data property to false in my setTimeout() function, the dom is not updated and so the v-if stays true.

**Watch:**

```js
watch: {
    selectedConfederations(newValue) {
      alert(newValue.length);
      if (newValue.length > 0) {
        this.showStepper = false;
        this.isLoading = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
          this.isLoading = false; /* This.isLoading will be false but DOM does not update and v-if stays on true and spinner will still be showing */
        }, 3000);
      } else {
        this.showStepper = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
  },
```

**Data:**

```js
data() {
    return {
      showStepper: true,
      isLoading: false,
    }
}
```

**Html:**

```html
<div v-if="isLoading">
          <v-layout row justify-center>
            <v-progress-circular
              :size="70"
              :width="7"
              color="primary"
              indeterminate
            ></v-progress-circular>
          </v-layout>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <v-layout row mt-2>
            <v-flex xs3>
              <v-card style="position:fixed" max-width="400">
                <v-toolbar row color="primary" dark>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-toolbar-title>
                      <v-icon dark>filter_alt</v-icon> Filter</v-toolbar-title
                    >
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8 style="padding-left: 50%;">
                    <v-tooltip bottom>
                      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn
                          style=""
                          color="white"
                          outline
                          small
                          fab
                          v-bind="attrs"
                          v-on="on"
                        >
                          <v-icon dark>autorenew</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                      </template>
                      <span>Reset filter</span>
                    </v-tooltip>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-card-text style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;">
                  <v-checkbox
                    label="Include girls"
                    color="primary"
                    hide-details
                  ></v-checkbox>
                  <v-checkbox
                    disabled
                    label="Include professional clubs only"
                    color="primary"
                    hide-details
                  ></v-checkbox>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-text style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;">
                  <h2 class="text-h6 mb-2">
                    Budget of clubs
                  </h2>
                  <v-chip
                    v-for="tag in filterItems.budgets"
                    :key="tag.id"
                    @click="() => selectedBudgetOption(tag)"
                    :outline="tag.selected ? false : true"
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    {{ tag.name }}
                  </v-chip>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-text style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;">
                  <h2 class="text-h6 mb-2">
                    Amount of players inside clubs
                  </h2>
                  <v-chip
                    v-for="tag in filterItems.playersizes"
                    :key="tag.id"
                    @click="() => selectedBudgetOption(tag)"
                    :outline="tag.selected ? false : true"
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    {{ tag.name }}
                  </v-chip>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-text>
                  <h2 class="text-h6 mb-2">
                    Teams available
                  </h2>
                  <v-chip
                    v-for="tag in filterItems.agegroups"
                    :key="tag.id"
                    @click="() => selectedBudgetOption(tag)"
                    :outline="tag.selected ? false : true"
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    {{ tag.name }}
                  </v-chip>
                </v-card-text>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs9>
              <v-layout>
                <RadarChart
                  :name="dimensionChart"
                  :title="dimensionChartTitle"
                />
              </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs3> </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs9>
              <v-layout>
                <RadarChart
                  :name="internationalStandardChart"
                  :title="internationalStandardChartTitle"
                />
              </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </div>
```

I think the problem is that the DOM is not being updated even when the watcher detects changes. The watcher is based on a v-model that is connected to a v-dropdown. All help is welcome and is much appreciated!

Comment: have you checked vue dev tool to check if the isLoading value has changed to true?

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't work because of this code :

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  this.isLoading = false; 
}, 3000);
```

In the code above, the value of `this` is different because you used a `function` which has a dynamic execution context (`this`).

--

To solve this problem you can store the value of `this` and then use it in the function :

```js
const that = this
setTimeout(() => {
  that.isLoading = false;
}, 3000)
```

You can also directly bind `this` of the method :

```
setTimeout(function () {
  this.isLoading = false;
}.bind(this), 3000)
```

Finally, the more convenient solution is to use an arrow function (which does not define its own `this`):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  this.isLoading = false;
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The isLoading is never returning to false because `this` in your setTimeout function is not referencing to the vue instance but to his own scope.

Making it an arrow function will fix this :

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.isLoading = false;
}, 3000);
```